# Black screen with white text after trying to update to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot

I have an issue that I can’t solve. I was trying to update my laptop to Ubuntu 16.04 but it froze during the update and it wouldn’t unfreeze so I was forced to press the power button to shut it down. When I rebooted, it looks like this: 
[black screen, white text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyzHk.jpg)

Did it get corrupted? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `sudo apt upgrade && reboot` or you can use `startx` after login, complete the upgrade process where it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Just typing `sudo <command>` does not actually do anything, as you can see from your error messages.

You need to type in the command you want, preceded by the word `sudo`. In your case, if you want to complete the upgrade, you need to type:

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

It will ask you for your password (enter it), and then it will most likely ask you to confirm that you want to do the release upgrade, just type `y` (for yes).

Comment: Hi @TerraGuth, please run `sudo apt update`, let it complete, and then do the same with `sudo apt -y upgrade` and `sudo apt -y dist-upgrade`. This should bring your 16.04 system fully up to date. Then please try to run `sudo do-release-upgrade` again. If this fails, you can do the upgrade manually. There is a guide [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver) under "How to update Ubuntu the Debian way"